# Angular - изменение выражения в контроллере

Tags: angularjs

Здравствуйте, есть перебор элементов модели и вывод их списком:

```
<div ng-controller="foo">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in items"> 
{{ item.ololo }}
<a ng-class="{'a1': !isActive, 'a2': isActive}" ng-click="isActive = !isActive"> ... </a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Также в каждой итерации в li-шку добавляется элемент при клике на который изменяется выражение isActive. 
Вопрос, как это выражение (isActive) изменить из контроллера которому принадлежит модель? 
Мне нужно чтобы при инициализации этого списка определенным элементам было установлено isActive = true, а другим false.

Comment: может в модели и держать этот параметр ? (если я вас правильно понял(

вроде такого

    items=[{'name':'name','isActive':0},{'name':'name1','isActive':1}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://plnkr.co/edit/9LzCBwZreOfzehTs4h7u?p=preview

Вот как-то так...

```
<div ng-controller="foo">
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="item in items"> 
{{ item.ololo }}
<a class="{{item.isActive?'a1':'a2'}}" ng-click="item.isActive = !item.isActive"> ... </a>
</li>
</ul>

var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('foo', function($scope) {
  $scope.items=[
    {'ololo':'Hello world',isActive: false},
    {'ololo':'Hello world1',isActive: true},
    {'ololo':'Hello world2',isActive: false},
    {'ololo':'Hello world3',isActive: false},
  ]
});
```